# Android: Buttons in MaterialButtonToggleGroup not showing on screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android

I am trying to add two buttons to my layouts using the MaterialButtonGroup tag however they do not show up in my app or in the design view of Android Studio.

This is in my build.gradle.  I've tried a few different versions.

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
```

This is my xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <import type="androidx.core.content.ContextCompat" />

        <import type="android.widget.Button"/>

    </data>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/backgroundWindow">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/backgroundCollection"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView_code"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Code"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_8dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <include layout="@layout/layout_seperator"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView_code"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

                    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:checkedButton="@id/b1"
                        app:selectionRequired="true"
                        app:singleSelection="true"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView_code"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

                        <Button
                            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
                            android:id="@+id/b1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="OPT1" />

                        <Button
                            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
                            android:id="@+id/b2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="OPT2" />

                    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>



                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>






        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</layout>
```

[And this is what I see in app (Imgur link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKE7U.png)

I've tried moving the buttons into different layouts, setting different width/heights, visibility but nothing has helped so far.

Comment: Your `layout_seperator` and `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` are overlapping - both are constrained to be  directly at the bottom of `textView_code`

Comment: @ltp Fixed that but still not showing.  Something I noticed is that even though the `layout_seperator` is constrained to the bottom of `textView_code`, the layout separator is still at the top of the layout

Comment: update your post with your edit and also show your `layout_separeter.xml` and theme/style.xml

Comment: @ltp I just ended up going with a different solution, thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, the buttons weren't visible on screen. They were visible on the design preview, though.

The solution was switching the `Button` to `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` inside the Group.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    android:id="@+id/toggle_button_group"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:singleSelection = "true"
    app:selectionRequired="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp"
    app:checkedButton="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        />
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button 2"
        />
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3"
        />

</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```